# How to use delete(_:) in Swift4 to Removes the selected content from your interface?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, interface, uikit

I have created a view programmatically

```
let v = UIView.init()
v.frame = CGRect(x:10, y:40, width:100, height:100)
v.backgroundcolor = .blue
view.addsubview(v)
```

to delete this view I used two different approaches

```
1:    v.ishidden = true
2:    v.removefromsuperview()

these two approaches don't completely erase v.frame & v.backgroundcolor values from memory just object disappears
```

then I use delete(_:)

```
v.delete(self)
```

it's giving an error

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

I think it's a syntax problem. how to use should I use it delete(_:)

```
optional func delete(_ sender: Any?)
```

Comment: You shouldn't. Once there are no more references to `v` it will be released. You don't need to worry about its properties such as frame and backgroundColor. ARC will take care of them.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Just remove the view from the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **do not** have to clean up the memory. Automatic Reference Counting will take care of this. When `v` goes out of scope, and no other object holds a reference to it, ARC will automatically release it from memory.

The `delete` method that you describe has nothing to do with memory management. You should not use it in this case.

So in your case, just use `v.removeFromSuperview()`, and all will be ok.

---

Extra: If `v` is a property (variable on the class instance), and you really really really want to remove it from memory, you can assign `nil` to it.